# Creating CSS3 shapes?

Tags: css, rotation, skew

I need to create this kind of element in css, lets say html

```
<h3 class="section-heading">Hello</h3>
```

[image]

But when i try like somethign like this

```
.section-heading:after{
-moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(359deg) translate(0px, 0px) skew(320deg, 0deg);
-webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(359deg) translate(0px, 0px) skew(320deg, 0deg);
-o-transform: scale(1) rotate(359deg) translate(0px, 0px) skew(320deg, 0deg);
-ms-transform: scale(1) rotate(359deg) translate(0px, 0px) skew(320deg, 0deg);
transform: scale(1) rotate(359deg) translate(0px, 0px) skew(320deg, 0deg);
}
```

Text also get rotate, even i have said after, where can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the text should not rotate if you apply the rotation to the pseudo-element.

but i suggest another solution to achieve that shape. ( this will work only in specific circumstances )

see here **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1pttvcLv/1/)**

add the desired `background-color` on the element, and with a pseudo-element like `:after` create a triangle with a `90deg` angle with the `background-color` of the container and position it on the right side of the `section-heading`

HTML

```
<h3 class="section-heading">Hello</h3>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background:#fff;
  }

.section-heading:after{
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 22px 22px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  right:0;
  top:0;

 }
 .section-heading {
   position:relative;
   color:#fff; 
   background:blue;
   width:200px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative to @Mihai's solution:

```css
body {
  background:#fff;
  }

.section-heading:after{
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
  right:-25px;
  top:0;

 }
 .section-heading {
   position:relative;
   color:#fff; 
   background:blue;
   width:200px;
 }
```

```html
<h3 class="section-heading">Hello</h3>
```